# UIViewController container with children for landscape/portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, landscape-portrait

I have an `UIViewController` container with two `UIViewController` children implementing two different way of browsing a collection of items (one coverflow, one list), one for each orientation (landscape/portrait). When you tap an item the container show another `UIViewController` child (this one is landscape/portrait compatible), providing details about the item.

When rotating, I would like an effect like in the Apple *Music* app on iOS, when you rotate the list, the list keeps its orientation and fade into the coverflow which is in the new orientation.

I can fade-out the list at the beginning of the rotation and fade-in the coverflow at the end but I can't fade the list into the coverflow (or any other animation involving the two views at the same time) because I don't know how to force the list to stay in portrait and the coverflow to stay in landscape.

I know I can force the container to stay in portrait with a `shouldAutorotate = NO` and use orientation notifications to show the landscape `UIViewController` as modal but I need the container to rotate in order to show my detail `UIViewController` in the right orientation.

I would like to keep a container with two children for each orientation but I would also accept a solution with a single `UIViewController` and two `UIView` for each orientation.

(iOS5+ compatibility is needed)

Comment: Using 2 UIViews is rather simple, I exchanged them in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.

Comment: If I exchange the two `UIView` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, for instance for the portrait->landscape rotation, the landscape `UIView` first show as portrait and then rotate and resize itself as landscape, it doesn't show as landscape at first.

Comment: Can you add the code for that method?